# How does grub-install / grub boot exactly work?

Tags: grub2, grub-legacy

Trying to make an USB with full installed Linux distros, I've landed on a bunch of pages (like this: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)) explaining how to install/reinstall grub on a device.

Trying to understand the procedures and methods, some questions raised:

- How `grub-install` command knows where to find (partitions of) O.S.s to boot?

I saw that - f.e. using a Linux USB live drive - we mount one of the partitions of the device where we want to install Grub and with the command: `for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done` we mount all the directory grub-install needs to locate all the O.S. installed on all the recognized devices (as all the devices under the /dev/ directory should be taken into consideration). Did I got it the right way? I also thought that, once you mount and set up everything, grub-install creates a configuration which tells grub where the O.S. to boot are located on the device... Is that right? Is this  configuration manually editable after the installation (e.g. Install a new S.O. and manually adding its boot instructions into grub configuration)?

- What are the exact differences among `grub-pc`, `grub-efi` and `grub-legacy` packages?

I know that grub can be installed both for legacy boot (boot with BIOS from MBR) and for EFI boot; but I also noticed that grub-install command, which you can launch after the installation of one among `grub-pc`, `grub-efi` and `grub-legacy` packages, have the `--efi-directory` parameter. This parameter allows you to specify where the ESP partition is mounted on the running system and, therefore, I think it allows to install Grub in EFI boot mode... Is this right? Does this mean that I can install Grub in EFI or BIOS mode with any of these packages? If yes, how? How can I specify that I want to install Grub in Bios or EFI mode with grub-install after the installation of one of these packages?
Moreover, I noticed that it seems you can install only one of these packages (if you already have one and try to install a different one with aptitude, aptitude marks the currently installed package for removal), why this happens?

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Answer (score 1):

Grub legacy is the old version of grub before grub2.
Many distributions converted to grub2 about 10 years ago. Often now when we say grub we mean grub2 as the old grub is called grub legacy.

The grub-pc package is for BIOS boot installs and use MBR to boot. If drive is gpt partitioned it also need a 1 or 2 MB unformatted partition with bios_grub flag.

The grub-efi-amd64 is for 64 bit PCs and UEFI boot. You need an ESP for grub-efi-amd64. Ubuntu lets you install in UEFI mode to 40 year old MBR(msdos) partitioned drives, but probably should not, but may allow it to prevent data loss of a conversion of a drive with data.
UEFI hightly recommends gpt partitioning.
Windows requires gpt for UEFI boot.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

Manual 2.04
https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.pdf

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer!
I read the help.ubuntu link and actually the story is now a lot clearer for me, thank you very much again.
Nevertheless, during my investigation I found out something I couldn't explain to myself: I tried to install grub in EFI mode using the grub-pc package (installed with chroot inside a sytem part. previously mounted from live) and I actually succeded... Isn't that weird? Shouldn't I be able to install grub in EFI mode only using the grub-efi package? Do you have any clues about how this happened?

Comment: Not sure. It used to be Ubuntu would only install either UEFI or BIOS version of grub. But I saw where they were going to allow both packages to be installed. Then grub may look for the mount of an ESP /efi/boot partition or files? and know you have UEFI and install using that or vice-versa. Only my system with mount of ESP in  fstab, I can reinstall UEFI version with just 'sudo grub-install` but that assumes a lot of defaults that in most cases should be expressly set.

Comment: Yeah maybe it just assumes a bunch of things based on the environment... In my tests, though, I found that the important thing was to specify the --target parameter. Setting it to x86_64-efi would install grub to the EFI partition (EFI mode), while setting it to i386_pc would install it to MBR (BIOS mode), regardless of the installed package. Maybe avoiding to set the parameter installs grub to MBR with grub-pc package installed or in EFI with grub-efi package installed... At least this is how it seems to me

Comment: Chapter 4 of manual also mentions ‘/usr/lib/grub/<cpu>-<platform>’ as image directory. Further down it mentions that if ESP is mounted at /boot/efi, then you only need sudo grub-install for UEFI. It also has lots more info on BIOS installs. I just searched pdf with 'grub-install'

Comment: Yeah, I did check the manual, but it seems do specify nothing about the differences between grub-pc and grub-efi packages, nor seems to explain if grub could be installed in EFI mode with grub-pc package or vice versa. 
Even in the 4.4 BIOS installation paragraph, the manual seems to only explain where grub should be installed for BIOS mode and how to partition the disk; saying nothing, though, on what of the two packages is to be used during installation.
That's another thing that makes me think grub could be installed in either of the two ways with both the packages...